# Запрет переноса/разрыва слов в таблице

Tags: html, table, outlook, width

Не кидайтесь в меня палками, если кому-то вопрос покажется простым. Прочтите до конца.
Имеется ежесуточная рассылка в корпоративной почте. В которую входят различные таблицы сравнения.

Mail subject: Мониторинг на сегодня

Mail Body:

| Месяц | Показатель на сервере 1 | Показатель на сервере 2 | Разница |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2020 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

В случае наличия разницы между показателями фон ячейки с разницей окрашивается в красный цвет. Само письмо заполняется на стороне `MS SQL` и отправляется с помощью `sp_send_dbmail`, где в параметр `@body` передаётся готовый `html`-код.

Таким образом пока все ячейки разницы не имеют красный фон, то само письмо просто сигнализирует об отсутствии проблем при сверки показателей между серверами. А когда появляется красный фон, то необходимо погружаться во все эти показатели.

Вся эта схема прекрасно работала, пока количество столбцов не превышало `10`. И названия столбцов и значения в таблице не переносились на новые строки.
Но! Если кому-то живётся спокойно, значит это надо исправить:
Появилась необходимость в одной таблице мониторить около `40` зависимых друг от друга показателей и соответственно их надо уместить в одну строку.
Естественно, при первом же прогоне письма выяснилось, что `width:100%` - это не наш метод, поэтому показатели ширины из этой конкретной таблицы были убраны. Это не принесло желаемых результатов. А результат должен быть таким, что:

1. Необязательно таблица должна быть в ширину письма, можно больше.
2. Желательно не переносить заголовки столбцов, но не критично.
3. Обязательно не переносить значения в столбцах - цифры (с плавающей точкой) должны быть в одну строку

В общем, если всё понятно, то вот что я уже попробовал

```
<td><nobr>Value</nobr></td>

<td nowrap>Value</td>

<td style="white-space: nowrap;">Value</td>
```

Так же игрался с фиксированием ширины столбцов. Не принесло успеха.
Для контроля письмо из `Outlook` я сохранял в `html`-страницу - смотрел код. Смутили добавленные `OutLook` классы типа

```
<p class=MsoNormal>01.2021</p>
```

Подозреваю, что проблема на стороне обработчика входящих писем `OutLook`. Пробовал ли кто решить эту проблему. Предварительное гугление не принесло результата.

**UPD:** И тапками не надо )
Пример того, что я отправляю в письме (если это имеет какой-то смысл :) ):

```
    <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
        <td>Месяц</td>
        <td>Показатель 1</td>
        <td>Показатель 2</td>
        <td>Показатель 3</td>
        <td>Показатель 4</td>
        <td>Показатель 5</td>
        <td>Показатель 6</td>
        <td>Показатель 7</td>
        <td>Показатель 8</td>
        <td>Показатель 9</td>
        <td>Показатель 10</td>
        <td>Показатель 11</td>
        <td>Показатель 12</td>
        <td>Показатель 13</td>
        <td>Показатель 14</td>
        <td>Показатель 15</td>
        <td>Показатель 16</td>
        <td>Показатель 17</td>
        <td>Показатель 18</td>
        <td>Показатель 19</td>
        <td>Показатель 20</td>
        <td>Показатель 21</td>
        <td>Показатель 22</td>
        <td>Показатель 23</td>
        <td>Показатель 24</td>
        <td>Показатель 25</td>
        <td>Показатель 26</td>
        <td>Показатель 27</td>
        <td>Показатель 28</td>
        <td>Показатель 29</td>
        <td>Показатель 30</td>
        <td>Показатель 31</td>
        <td>Показатель 32</td>
        <td>Показатель 33</td>
        <td>Показатель 34</td>
        <td>Показатель 35</td>
        <td>Показатель 36</td>
        <td>Показатель 37</td>
        <td>Показатель 38</td>
        <td>Показатель 39</td>
        <td>Показатель 40</td>
        <td>Разница</td>
    </tr>
...
    <tr>
        <td>01.2021</td>
        <td>Значение 1</td>
        <td>Значение 2</td>
        <td>Значение 3</td>
        <td>Значение 4</td>
        <td>Значение 5</td>
        <td>Значение 6</td>
        <td>Значение 7</td>
        <td>Значение 8</td>
        <td>Значение 9</td>
        <td>Значение 10</td>
        <td>Значение 11</td>
        <td>Значение 12</td>
        <td>Значение 13</td>
        <td>Значение 14</td>
        <td>Значение 15</td>
        <td>Значение 16</td>
        <td>Значение 17</td>
        <td>Значение 18</td>
        <td>Значение 19</td>
        <td>Значение 20</td>
        <td>Значение 21</td>
        <td>Значение 22</td>
        <td>Значение 23</td>
        <td>Значение 24</td>
        <td>Значение 25</td>
        <td>Значение 26</td>
        <td>Значение 27</td>
        <td>Значение 28</td>
        <td>Значение 29</td>
        <td>Значение 30</td>
        <td>Значение 31</td>
        <td>Значение 32</td>
        <td>Значение 33</td>
        <td>Значение 34</td>
        <td>Значение 35</td>
        <td>Значение 36</td>
        <td>Значение 37</td>
        <td>Значение 38</td>
        <td>Значение 39</td>
        <td>Значение 40</td>
        <td>Значение разницы</td>
    </tr>
..
</table>
```

Вопрос именно в том, как уместить столько столбцов на одном листе без переноса значений в ячейках.

**UPD2**: Вот что приходит в письме.

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='mso-cellspacing:0cm;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Месяц<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 1</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 2</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 3</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 4</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 5</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 6</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 7</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 8</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 9</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 10</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 11</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 12</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 13</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 14</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 15</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 16</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 17</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 18</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 19</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 20</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 21</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 22</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 23</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 24</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 25</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 26</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 27</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 28</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 29</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 30</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 31</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 32</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 33</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 34</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 35</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 36</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 37</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 38</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 39</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 40</p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Разница</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>01.2020<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 1<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 2<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 3<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 4<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 5<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 6<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 7<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 8<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 9<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 10<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
                <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>01.2020<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 11<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 12<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 13<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 14<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 15<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 16<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 17<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 18<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 19<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 20<o:p></o:p></p>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 21<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 22<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 23<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 24<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 25<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 26<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 27<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 28<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 29<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 30<o:p></o:p></p>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 31<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 32<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 33<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 34<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 35<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 36<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 37<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 38<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 39<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Значение 40<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
        <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>Разница<o:p></o:p></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

И вопрос именно в том, откуда появляются в td параметры style, и кто оборачивает значения в абзац да ещё и в класс оформления. Причём на стороне БД я этого не делаю. Потому и предположил, что это делает Outlook. А вот как это обойти - именно в этом мой вопрос ))). Наконец-то Вы помогли мне его правильно описать и сформулировать. Спасибо Вам большое!

**UPD3**: класс MsoNormal

```
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' , Поправил начальный пост

Comment: <nobr> тег для этого есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a , пробовал. В посте описано.

Comment: @Sevastopol' , Попробовал. Не помогло. А в чём различия между <td><nobr>Показатель 10</nobr></td> и <td><p><nobr>Показатель 10</nobr></p></td>?

Answer (score 0):

Или я чего-то не понимаю, или что-то еще. Почему у вас не работает свойство `white-space: nowrap;`? Ну здесь же работает, ничего не переносится:

```css
td {white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
  <tr>
    <td>Месяц</td>
    <td>Показатель 1</td>
    <td>Показатель 2</td>
    <td>Показатель 3</td>
    <td>Показатель 4</td>
    <td>Показатель 5</td>
    <td>Показатель 6</td>
    <td>Показатель 7</td>
    <td>Показатель 8</td>
    <td>Показатель 9</td>
    <td>Показатель 10</td>
    <td>Показатель 11</td>
    <td>Показатель 12</td>
    <td>Показатель 13</td>
    <td>Показатель 14</td>
    <td>Показатель 15</td>
    <td>Показатель 16</td>
    <td>Показатель 17</td>
    <td>Показатель 18</td>
    <td>Показатель 19</td>
    <td>Показатель 20</td>
    <td>Показатель 21</td>
    <td>Показатель 22</td>
    <td>Показатель 23</td>
    <td>Показатель 24</td>
    <td>Показатель 25</td>
    <td>Показатель 26</td>
    <td>Показатель 27</td>
    <td>Показатель 28</td>
    <td>Показатель 29</td>
    <td>Показатель 30</td>
    <td>Показатель 31</td>
    <td>Показатель 32</td>
    <td>Показатель 33</td>
    <td>Показатель 34</td>
    <td>Показатель 35</td>
    <td>Показатель 36</td>
    <td>Показатель 37</td>
    <td>Показатель 38</td>
    <td>Показатель 39</td>
    <td>Показатель 40</td>
    <td>Разница</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01.2021</td>
    <td>Значение 1</td>
    <td>Значение 2</td>
    <td>Значение 3</td>
    <td>Значение 4</td>
    <td>Значение 5</td>
    <td>Значение 6</td>
    <td>Значение 7</td>
    <td>Значение 8</td>
    <td>Значение 9</td>
    <td>Значение 10</td>
    <td>Значение 11</td>
    <td>Значение 12</td>
    <td>Значение 13</td>
    <td>Значение 14</td>
    <td>Значение 15</td>
    <td>Значение 16</td>
    <td>Значение 17</td>
    <td>Значение 18</td>
    <td>Значение 19</td>
    <td>Значение 20</td>
    <td>Значение 21</td>
    <td>Значение 22</td>
    <td>Значение 23</td>
    <td>Значение 24</td>
    <td>Значение 25</td>
    <td>Значение 26</td>
    <td>Значение 27</td>
    <td>Значение 28</td>
    <td>Значение 29</td>
    <td>Значение 30</td>
    <td>Значение 31</td>
    <td>Значение 32</td>
    <td>Значение 33</td>
    <td>Значение 34</td>
    <td>Значение 35</td>
    <td>Значение 36</td>
    <td>Значение 37</td>
    <td>Значение 38</td>
    <td>Значение 39</td>
    <td>Значение 40</td>
    <td>Значение разницы</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как @nick_n_a написал в комментарии, тег `<nobr>` ([ссылка](http://htmlbook.ru/html/nobr)) может быть как вариант. В случае, если Outlook при добавлении своих классов указывает стили, которые нарушают вывод. Попробовать так (если конечно он его не будет вырезать):

```
<td><nobr>Показатель</nobr></td>
```

```css
nobr {color: red;}

.MsoNormal {white-space: normal;}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
  <tr>
    <td>Месяц</td>
    <td><nobr>Показатель 1</nobr></td>
    <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'><p class=MsoNormal>Показатель 2</p></td>
    <td style='padding:2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt 2.4pt'><p class=MsoNormal><nobr>Показатель 3</nobr></p></td>
    <td>Показатель 4</td>
    <td>Показатель 5</td>
    <td>Показатель 6</td>
    <td>Показатель 7</td>
    <td>Показатель 8</td>
    <td>Показатель 9</td>
    <td>Показатель 10</td>
    <td>Показатель 11</td>
    <td>Показатель 12</td>
    <td>Показатель 13</td>
    <td>Показатель 14</td>
    <td>Показатель 15</td>
    <td>Показатель 16</td>
    <td>Показатель 17</td>
    <td>Показатель 18</td>
    <td>Показатель 19</td>
    <td>Показатель 20</td>
    <td>Показатель 21</td>
    <td>Показатель 22</td>
    <td>Показатель 23</td>
    <td>Показатель 24</td>
    <td>Показатель 25</td>
    <td>Показатель 26</td>
    <td>Показатель 27</td>
    <td>Показатель 28</td>
    <td>Показатель 29</td>
    <td>Показатель 30</td>
    <td>Показатель 31</td>
    <td>Показатель 32</td>
    <td>Показатель 33</td>
    <td>Показатель 34</td>
    <td>Показатель 35</td>
    <td>Показатель 36</td>
    <td>Показатель 37</td>
    <td>Показатель 38</td>
    <td>Показатель 39</td>
    <td>Показатель 40</td>
    <td>Разница</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01.2021</td>
    <td>Значение 1</td>
    <td>Значение 2</td>
    <td>Значение 3</td>
    <td>Значение 4</td>
    <td>Значение 5</td>
    <td>Значение 6</td>
    <td>Значение 7</td>
    <td>Значение 8</td>
    <td>Значение 9</td>
    <td>Значение 10</td>
    <td>Значение 11</td>
    <td>Значение 12</td>
    <td>Значение 13</td>
    <td>Значение 14</td>
    <td>Значение 15</td>
    <td>Значение 16</td>
    <td>Значение 17</td>
    <td>Значение 18</td>
    <td>Значение 19</td>
    <td>Значение 20</td>
    <td>Значение 21</td>
    <td>Значение 22</td>
    <td>Значение 23</td>
    <td>Значение 24</td>
    <td>Значение 25</td>
    <td>Значение 26</td>
    <td>Значение 27</td>
    <td>Значение 28</td>
    <td>Значение 29</td>
    <td>Значение 30</td>
    <td>Значение 31</td>
    <td>Значение 32</td>
    <td>Значение 33</td>
    <td>Значение 34</td>
    <td>Значение 35</td>
    <td>Значение 36</td>
    <td>Значение 37</td>
    <td>Значение 38</td>
    <td>Значение 39</td>
    <td>Значение 40</td>
    <td>Значение разницы</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вот как это приходит в тесте собщения Outlook

Comment: Поправил основной пост. Суть вопроса собственно изменилась ))